# MaTeX and \phantom

Tags: output-formatting, latex, matex

My understanding of the \phantom directive is that it should preserve the sizes of all elements in the expression. But when I try this:

```
m1 = Inset[MaTeX["\\sqrt{\\phantom{a^2}b}", Magnification -> 5], {0, 0}];

m2 = Inset[MaTeX["\\sqrt{a^2b}", Magnification -> 5], {0, 0}];

Graphics[{m1, m2}]
```

I get this:

[image]

I would have expected the two square roots to be right on top of each other.

Comment: Please use code blocks for code, not quote blocks, otherwise some of the code might be destroyed (as it was here).

Comment: That's a very strange position for one of the b's!

Answer (score 12):

The same sizes show up using pure Latex.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\Huge
\[
\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}
\]

\[
\sqrt{a^2b}
\]

\end{document}
```

Gives (compiled with pdflatex)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is inside Mathematica:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see any difference. But I think your question is really about Latex itself and not Matex, which just compiles using Latex.

You could see this [how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/how-do-i-create-an-invisible-character) on Tex Exchange where it says

> \phantom inserts an empty box with the same dimensions (horizontal as
>   well as vertical) as the argument

But if you think it is not doing what it should, I would suggest asking at https://tex.stackexchange.com

**Update**

What  you want is `\hphantom` and not `\phantom`

```
m1=Inset[MaTeX["\\sqrt{\\hphantom{a^2}b}",Magnification->5],{0,0}]
m2=Inset[MaTeX["\\sqrt{a^2b}",Magnification->5],{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{m1,m2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In plain TeX, `$\sqrt{\phantom{a^2}b}$` and `$\sqrt{{a^2}b}$` seem to coincide. (It could be that LaTeX messes things up. I'm not sure how to use it.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 that is interesting,. But no one uses Plain TeX anymore, well may be except for Donald Knuth himself :) This could be a good question for tex exchange to explain this difference between TeX and Latex.

Comment: And me. :-)  Too many packages written in years gone by....When LaTeX came out, it seemed like the kid's version. ;-P -- Wait, do they not coincide in LaTeX? I didn't think LaTeX did anything drastic to TeX, unlike ConTeXt....

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just compiled using plain TeX using `\phantom` and the output is the same as with Latex as shown in the post. i.e. Same spacing difference. They do not coincide.  I am using texlive 2017 on Linux. ps. I tried to learn Context, but it is really a completely different system from Latex, so I decided not worth the time.

Comment: Isn't that interesting.  I'm using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015), MacOS.  I wouldn't think plain TeX would have changed, and from what I know about plain TeX, they should coincide.  Ah, well.   However, I get the OP's output using MaTeX.

Comment: @MichaelE2 if you get different result from Tex Vs. Latex using `\phantom` I think you might want to consider posting this at Tex Exchange as this should not happen and you could have found a bug. It does not happen for me on Latest TeXLive 2017.